# VBA Loop to find records not working

Tags: vba, loops

I have been trying to get this code to work. But having no luck. I have rebuilt it, and tested at each point. But when I get to the if part it seems to fail.
But for some reason the code is not copying and pasting any search information.

```
Sub copy()

Dim company As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'row counter

sheets("sheet1").Range("m2:s5000").ClearContents

company = sheets("Sheet1").Range("k2").Value

lastrow = sheets("sheet1").Range("A2000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To final

        If Cells(i, 1) = company Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 10)).copy
            Range("J100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

        End If

Next i

Range("a6").Select

End Sub
```

The plan is to use the code to search through monthly information and return all suppliers from a specific list.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `final`?  It's not defined in the code you've provided.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Sounds like this could be re-designed with `VLOOKUP` instead of VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never declare and initialize `final`.  To help avoid bugs like this, go to "Tools" > "Options", select the "Editor" tab, and check the "Require Variable Declaration" box.